# Multithreading with Strings in C

Tags: c, string, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

I have a problem with my code, maybe one of you might help me. 
Let's try to be short...
I have a school project to do, and it requires pipes and threads(PL=C, SO=Debian).  The program is running fine, except for one little error that is robbing me of hours of sleep.

I put my 'thread' to make the file access of the program, so... it just have to open the files, save the data, and save a 'report' of parts of the file in a string, so that the 'shell' can show it to the user.

But the problem is that, if i print the string(global) inside the thread, the string has the data, and it's printed, but if i let to print in the 'shell part of the program' the string is empty, no data at all... Below are the key parts of the code, if anyone can help me, i'll be very grateful.
Btw, sorry about my english, not my native language.

That is the thread function

```
void *acessaDisco(void *arg)
{
    int op;
    op = (int) arg;

    switch(op)
    {
        case 1:
            //salva no disco
            //sem_wait(&semaforoControleTextoThread);
            if(escrevePersonagemArquivo(personagemTempThread)==TRUE){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&tranca);
                sprintf(textoThread,"\n\nSeu personagem foi salvo corretamente!\n\n");
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&tranca);          
            }
            else{
                pthread_mutex_lock(&tranca);
                sprintf(textoThread,"\n\nOcorreu um erro ao tentar salvar seu personagem...\n\n");
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&tranca);
            }
            //sem_post(&semaforoControleTextoThread);
            break;
        case 2:
            //encontra personagem no arquivo
            //sem_wait(&semaforoControleTextoThread);
            if(encontraPersonagem(nomeBuscaPersonagem,&personagemTempThread)==FALSE){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&tranca);
                sprintf(textoThread, "\n\nInfelizmente, o personagem %s não foi encontrado... :(\n\n", nomeBuscaPersonagem);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&tranca);
            }
            else{
                pthread_mutex_lock(&tranca);
                imprimeFichaTemp(personagemTempThread, textoThread);
                strcpy(auxiliarTeste, textoThread);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&tranca);
                //printf("\n\n\nDepois bloquear mutex, string: %s", textoThread);
            }
            //sem_post(&semaforoControleTextoThread);
            break;
    }

    return NULL;

}
```

Here is where i call it from...

```
case 300:
        //procura o personagem
        strcpy(nomeBuscaPersonagem, buff+4*sizeof(char));
        pthread_create(&threadAcessaDisco, NULL, acessaDisco, (int)2);
        break;
```

And finally, where i print it

```
case 2:
            fflush(stdout);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\n\nAntes Tela Visualizacao\n\n");
            telaVisualizacao(writefd);
            fflush(stdout);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\n\nAntesSemWaitClient\n\n");
            //sem_wait(&semaforoControleTextoThread);
            printf("\n\nDepoisSemWaitClient\n\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            fflush(stdin);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&tranca);
            printf("\n\nTexto Thread:%s Texto aux: %s\n\n", textoThread, auxiliarTeste);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&tranca);
            fflush(stdout);
            fflush(stdin);
            //sem_post(&semaforoControleTextoThread);
            getchar();
            break;
```

If any additional information is needed, i'll be glad to provide!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Doing `fflush` on `stdin` is technically undefined behavior, it's an extension in certain libraries, but if you want to keep your code portable you should not do it. Also, `stdout` is by default line buffered, so `stdout` is flushed automatically when a newline is printed, so you don't have to do it. And lastly, on those systems where doing `fflush` on `stdin` is supported, it only needs to be done before you read input, not every time you print anything.

Comment: There is plenty unclear here. You create your thread on `case 300`, but you print on `case 2`, where aparently no thread is created. Also, you don't seem to be waiting for the thread to prepare `textoThread` before printing it anywhere.

Comment: Also, your use of `nomeBuscaPersonagem` is not protected, so if you set it for one thread, but then change it before the thread gets a chance to use it, the thread will use the updated string.

Comment: Aparently you were trying to use semaphores in your code (that you comment out). Thats important, you need them. I only don't see `sem_init()` being used, which is important.

Comment: well, lets go by parts

Comment: I was using semaphores, the inits are in other parts of the code, i switched to mutex just to see if the problem was with the semaphores, but it wasn't :)
The fflush's are because the printf's wasnt showing without them, when i fix the other problems i'm gonna remove them one by one to see wich ones are really necessary :)
About the switch cases, i forgot to mention, they're in different functions.

The problem though, was a really dumb one, i even feel embarrassed right now, i used fork(), then i was creating the thread in one subproccess and trying to print the value in the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee that the thread will have executed by the time you try to retrieve the value.

You need to use a semaphore in the main thread which waits on the thread you've created. That thread then needs to post to the semaphore, which lets the main thread know that it may retrieve the value.

Mutexes are locking primitives: they allow you to guarantee mutually exclusive access to a resource. They do not by themselves provide synchronization (sequenced execution). To achieve this, you should use a semaphore. It looks like from the comments you have some idea of that, but you had trouble getting it to work.

This is the sequence your program should run:

1. main thread: initialize semaphore (to 0), create the target thread with a pointer to the semaphore. sem_wait on the created semaphore just before needing the value. Execution will block.
2. target thread: set the shared (global) value, post to the semaphore.
3. main thread: now resumes execution after the value has been initialized in your target thread, and the value should be populated.

Comment: Ummm... my reading of POSIX is that the value of the semaphore is always *unsigned*, so initialising it to -1 looks dodgy to me.

Comment: Err I don't know how that got there. It should say 0. Edited. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks a lot by the tips :) The problem though, was that i was trying to access the string from another subproccess, silly me :D
Anyway, i'm gonna use your tips to finish the project now.
Thanks a lot again!